# How to extend a bounded type in java

Tags: java, generics, bounded-types

How do we extend a bounded generic type in Java? For example, I have an abstract class as below:

```
public abstract class Entry<K, V extends EntryIterable<V>> {
    private Entry<K, V> next;
    private Entry<K, V> previous;
    private K key;
    private V value;
}
```

Let's say I have a couple of methods that I would like to implement in the subclass. So when I try to extend this class I get the below error message.

```
public class Record<K, V> extends Entry<K, V> {
    public Record(K key, V value) {
        super(key, value);
    }
}

ERROR: Bound mismatch: The type V is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <V extends EntryIterable<V>> of the type Entry<K,V>
```

Please help. Let me know if I made a mistake.

Comment: Why isn't `Record`'s `V` bounded?

Answer (score 2):

In `Entry` class, you expect `V` type to extends `EntryIterable<V>`. So in `Record` and all its subclasses, as it extends `Entry`, you must ask `V` to extends `EntryIterable<V>` as well.

That's said, this will work:

```
public class Record<K, V extends EntryIterable<V>> extends Entry<K, V> {
```

---

You could also have stronger type. I mean, if you have a class `EntryIterableAndRemovable` that extends `EntryIterable`, you could do:

```
public class Record<K, V extends EntryIterableAndRemovable<V>> extends Entry<K, V> {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should copy `V extends EntryIterable<V>` to the `Record` or else the compiler can't be sure that this restriction always holds for all `Entry` subclasses:

```
public class Record<K, V extends EntryIterable<V>> extends Entry<K, V> {
```